# zend studio debugger timing out

Tags: putty, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I am attempting to setup a remote profiling session with a server. I have downloaded the latest version of Zend Debugger, and have installed it on the server with the following setup - http://puu.sh/3ezyh/39247f2f15.png . With my local machine, I have setup a putty session to the remote server, and forwarded port 10137 as per the KB article listed on zend.com.

I am able to debug the remote server without a problem, however when I goto profile the page, the page will process, then a dialog will pop up with a "Waiting for the debugger's response" message. After approximately ~20 seconds, I get the following error: http://puu.sh/3ezDk/57f6dc1bb5.png .
However, there will be profiling information displayed , as well as execution statistics, but no execution flow, almost like it's getting part of the data but not all of it.

The page in question does have anywhere from a 20-30 second page load (which is why I'm tyring to profile to find the problem.)

The only error I can find is in the server's error_log, which just says "[Zend Debugger] Cannot send message"

Is there anyway to diagnose why I'm not getting the complete response?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is getting your IP address and trying to send directly to it instead of over the local forwarded connection.  You might need to set your host IP to 127.0.0.1 as the address like in http://screencast.com/t/7lheaOlx.  If that doesn't work I would say do a

```
tcpdump port 10137
```

And see what you can see.  Also, depending on your local OS you may have a firewall blocking access to your instance of Studio.

Comment: I did setup my IP for the server debugger to 127.0.0.1 like in that example, and when hitting [Test] under Profile Configuration, it also throws up a warning about _Old Debugger version found. Please update your Zend Debugger version_, which I've already done. (Both Zend Studio & Zen Debugger are updated to latest versions that I could find via zend links)

When running `tcp dump 10137` on the server I'm connected to, nothing is output when trying to test, so I'm assuming that means that a connection isn't being made somewhere.

Comment: My putty log shows these lines in the event log every time I try to test it
`Received remote port 10137 open request from 127.0.0.1:46510 (different each connection request)
Attempting to forward remote port to 127.0.0.1:10137
Forwarded port opened successfully
Forwarded port closed`